# ICU-Project with MinGW and Netbeans - undefined reference

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw, undefined-reference, icu

I configured MinGW and the ICU-Project source like shown [there](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Compiling-ICU-with-MinGW).

I tried to compile this code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <timezone.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistr.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    UnicodeString id;
    TimeZone* tz =  TimeZone::createTimeZone(id);   
    int32_t raw,dst;
    int64_t when = 1367836520*U_MILLIS_PER_SECOND;
    UErrorCode ec = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    tz->getOffset((UDate)when,FALSE,raw,dst,ec);
    cout<<raw<<endl;
    cout<<dst<<endl;   
}
```

And I get following compiler errors:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Florian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Florian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -I../../../../../MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/unicode -I../../../../../MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In Funktion �int main(int, char**)�:
main.cpp:27:31: Warnung: Ganzzahl�berlauf in Ausdruck [-Woverflow]
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o 
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Florian\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `icu_51::TimeZone::createTimeZone(icu_51::UnicodeString const&)'
C:\Users\Florian\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `icu_51::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
C:\Users\Florian\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `icu_51::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `ZN6icu_517UObjectC2Ev':
C:\Users\Florian\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/../../../../../MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/unicode/uobject.h:221: undefined reference to `vtable for icu_51::UObject'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `ZN6icu_5111ReplaceableC2Ev':
C:\Users\Florian\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/../../../../../MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/unicode/rep.h:240: undefined reference to `vtable for icu_51::Replaceable'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `ZN6icu_5113UnicodeStringC1Ev':
C:\Users\Florian\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1/../../../../../MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include/unicode/unistr.h:3615: undefined reference to `vtable for icu_51::UnicodeString'
collect2.exe: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zur�ck
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Florian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Florian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Any ideas what these errors mean?

```
main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `icu_51::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
```

These errors are in header files I wanna use from the ICU-Project, what is going on?

Comment: obviously there are some lib's missing. Check the documentation to find out what you have to link (-lXXX)

Comment: I tried to compile it with MinGW and Microsoft Visual c++- Compiler in Eclipse with the MS compilter it does work, but i need the MinGW, used the same libs

Comment: You can not use MS precompiled libs with mingw.

Comment: Thank you for this question, I have the same problem. From everything that was posted so far, it seems that the comment by @moskito-x might be the reason. Then we would have to compile our own ICU for MinGW. Have you had any success by now?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

> main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `icu_51::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'

The error above means that the linker cannot find the definition of the UnicodeString destructor.

You have to link in your project the corresponding libraries: icuin (due to `undefined reference to icu_51::TimeZone::createTimeZone`), icuuc (due to `undefined reference to icu_51::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()`).

I had to link icudt as well.

Look up the proper library names in your path/to/icu/lib directory. For example for static icu they are: sicuuc, sicuin, sicust, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The cause of your error:

```
main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `icu_51::UnicodeString::~UnicodeString()'
```

Means there is missing a definition of the named method.  For example, here is a barebones C++ program that throws this kind of error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class utilities{
public:
  void myfunction();
};
int main() {
    utilities util;
    util.myfunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Throws the error:

```
main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `utilities::myfunction()'
```

Notice that utilities::myfunction was never defined.  To fix this, you have to include a definition of the missing functions.  Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class utilities{
public:
  void myfunction();
};
int main() {
    utilities util;
    util.myfunction();
    return 0;
}
void utilities::myfunction(){   
}
```

Then it compiles without error.